# c# references a uses b that inherits from c

Tags: c#, .net, reference

I have classes A,B,C like this:

```
//Class A is in Console application that has reference to class library that has class B
public class A
{
    public void UseBObject()
    {
       B BInstance=new B();   // error C is defined in assembly that is not referenced you must add  reference that contains C... 
    }
} 


//Class library that reference another library the contains C class
public class B : C
{
   public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

My question is if B already has reference to C and A has reference to B why do A need to have reference to C?
This is not make sense no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume class `C` is defined as below, which defines a property called `PropertyInC`

```
public class C
{
   public string PropertyInC {get;set;}
}
```

Then when use C's public members through B's instance like this.

```
public void UseBObject()
{
   B BInstance=new B();
   BInstance.PropertyInC = "Whatever";
}
```

How come compiler will know what is `PropertyInC`? Did you gave any clue about what type it is? Or How does the compiler even get a chance to know whether such property exist ?

Well, you could argue that compiler can find that using the assembly reference of *AsselblyB(assembly where B lives)* but then there is no guarantee that referenced assembly will there in the the same path or whatsoever. If not exist it will fail at runtime :)

Also note that compiler will allow you to compile if you don't have inheritance relationship, but then if you need to access `b.CMember` you definitely gonna add reference to assembly where `C` exist.

```
public class B
{
   private C CMember{get;set;}//This will compile
   public string Name{get;set;}
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks really helped to understand!

Answer (score 0):

Because B is a C, so to create a C, A needs to know about it because it's part of the public surface area of a B.

Comment: yes but A reference B and B reference C so why A not "know" C and if C is D so A need to reference the library of D also??? I dont understand why???

Comment: It's the way the compiler works.  Just because you can't *see* it in the code doesn't mean the compiler and runtime can't.  Creating a B necessitates having access to the constructor of a C, hence the requirement.