# Why does a client project need reference both to the base and the intermediate project?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, dll

I have 3 projects: the base one, intermediate and client. Client access base project trough intermediate one. I simplified here my problem. I have a solution with 3 projects:

```
// Animals project
public class FarmAnimal
{
    public string GetFood { get; protected set; }
}

public class Cow : FarmAnimal
{
    public Cow()
    {
        GetFood = "Milk";
    }

}

public class Chicken : FarmAnimal
{
    public Chicken()
    {
        GetFood = "Egg";
    }

}

// Farmer project
public class AbstractFarmer<TAnimal> where TAnimal : FarmAnimal, new()
{
    protected TAnimal animal = new TAnimal();
    public string GetProduct()
    {
        return animal.GetFood;
    }
}

public class CowFarmer: AbstractFarmer<Cow>
{

}

public class ChickenFarmer : AbstractFarmer<Chicken>
{

}

// Client project
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var cowFarmer = new CowFarmer();
        Console.WriteLine(cowFarmer.GetProduct());
    }
}
```

If the client project doesn't add reference to the animals, then it gives:

> Error 1 The type 'Animals.FarmAnimal' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Animals, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'.

The principle of encapsulation says that the client should not know about "Animals", only about the intermediate ("Farmers").

How can I solve this problem and why does it appear?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c# references a uses b that inherits from c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22893988/c-sharp-references-a-uses-b-that-inherits-from-c)

Comment: "The principle of encapsulation says that the client should not know about "Animals"" - then why did you break this "encapsulation" in your `Farmer` project and expose the `Cow` and `Chicken` types as part of defining your `CowFarmer` and `ChickenFarmer` classes?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the Farmer Project to

```
    public class AbstractFarmer
    {
        protected FarmAnimal animal;
        public string GetProduct()
        {
            return animal.GetFood;
        }
    }

    public class CowFarmer : AbstractFarmer
    {
        public CowFarmer()
        {
            animal = new Cow();
        }
    }

    public class ChickenFarmer : AbstractFarmer
    {
        public ChickenFarmer()
        {
            animal = new Chicken();
        }
    }
```

and it should work fine.

What happens is, when you provide the dynamic `<Type>` explicitly to `AbstractFarmer` class, you are necessarily binding your Farmer implementation with a type argument of Animal required which throws the error.

Explanation :

From [MSDN Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0zk36dx2.aspx),

> a type parameters is a placeholder for a specific type that a client
>   specifies when they instantiate a variable of the generic type

which means that any *instance variable* of a class which expects a Generic Type parameter must, while its instantiation, pass the Type required for it.
In your case, you would not need to pass the type during instantiation

```
var cowFarmer = new CowFarmer();
```

because you have specified the Type parameter along with the class. (If you double click on the error, assuming you are using Visual Studio, it will even point you to the above line.)

```
public class CowFarmer: AbstractFarmer<Cow>
```

However, upon instantiation, the `Cow` class is now required to be bound with the `cowFarmer` variable (which is present in the **Client assembly**) and that variable to instantiate completely would require a reference to the **Animals assembly** which has the `Cow` class in it.

I think, this is the cause of your confusion - the `Type` `Cow`, not being directly visible at the time of `cowFarmer` instantiation.

Comment: Yes it works. :) Can you please add more explanations of why it works?